# Restore documents from its old version at one time in document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, versioning

I have 300 documents in a document library and i want to restore all documents from its old version.Each document has two version v 1.0 and v 2.0 is there any way to restore all documents from its old version 1.0 one time instead of selecting each document its take time.

i want to restore from its old version only documents created date less than 05/01/2017 or Filesize=1KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to automate this task using code. You can use CSOM to achieve this

VB: (you can use C# too)

```
Sub Main()

       Dim caml As String = "CAMLSTATEMENT HERE"
       Dim camlQry As New CamlQuery()
       camlQry.ViewXml = caml

       Dim ctx As New Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("REPLACE BY YOUR SERVER URL")
       Dim list As List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Meetresultaten STM")
       ctx.Load(list)
       ctx.ExecuteQuery()

       If Not list Is Nothing Then
           Dim documents As ListItemCollection = list.GetItems(camlQry)
           ctx.Load(documents)
           ctx.ExecuteQuery()

           For Each document As ListItem In documents
               ctx.Load(document)
               ctx.ExecuteQuery()

               Dim docFile As File = document.File
               ctx.Load(docFile)
               ctx.ExecuteQuery()

               ctx.Load(docFile.Versions)
               ctx.ExecuteQuery()
               Dim v As FileVersion = docFile.Versions(docFile.Versions.Count - 1)
               ctx.Load(v)
               ctx.ExecuteQuery()

               If Not v Is Nothing Then
                   Console.WriteLine("FILE: {0} : {1} from: {2}", v.VersionLabel, v.Url, v.Created.ToShortDateString)
                   docFile.Versions.RestoreByLabel(v.VersionLabel)
                   ctx.ExecuteQuery()
               End If
           Next
       End If
       Console.WriteLine("Finished!")
       Console.ReadKey()
   End Sub
```

Powershell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2010
$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]
$items = $list.Items
foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $file = $item.File
    $fileVersions = $file.Versions      
    if ($fileVersions.Count -gt 0)
    {           
        $fileVersions.Restore($fileVersions.Count - 1)          
    }   
}
```

Comment: added powershell code too

Comment: You need to use SP Query.

Comment: $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
$camlQuery = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + dtStartDate + "</Value></Geq>" + "<Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + dtEndDate + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";
$spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
$sourceItems = $sourceList.GetItems($spQuery)

Comment: Make sure that the date is ISO format

Comment: and also it has some documents versions 4 v1.0,v2.0,v3.0 ?

Comment: u can use conditional statements for that